# How can I change the colorscheme through command line?

Tags: colors, linux-terminal, konsole

I'm using [`base16` theme](https://github.com/cskeeters/base16-konsole/)

```
$ ls ~/.kde/apps/konsole/
base16-tomorrow.colorscheme  base16-tomorrow-night.colorscheme
```

My scheme are correctly installed

[image: selection_018]

But when I try to switch using `konsoleprofile` it's not working:

```
konsoleprofile "ColorScheme=Base16TomorrowNight 
konsoleprofile "colors=Base16TomorrowNight"
```

**related:**

- asked [on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/1193957/174465)
- [Changing Konsole colors in KDE using the shell](https://abdussamad.com/archives/503-Changing-Konsole-colors-in-KDE.html)
- [nareshv/kde-konsole-colorschemes#3](https://github.com/nareshv/kde-konsole-colorschemes/issues/3)
- [cskeeters/base16-konsole#4](https://github.com/cskeeters/base16-konsole/issues/4)

Answer (score 0):

#### Without `tmux`

```
konsoleprofile "colors=base16-tomorrow-night"
konsoleprofile "colors=base16-tomorrow"
```

The value is the name of the scheme files without extension:

```
$ ls ~/.kde/apps/konsole/
base16-tomorrow.colorscheme
base16-tomorrow-night.colorscheme
```

#### Inside `tmux`

```
printf '\033Ptmux;\033\033]50;%s\007\033\\' "colors=base16-tomorrow"
printf '\033Ptmux;\033\033]50;%s\007\033\\' "colors=base16-tomorrow-night"
```